# Why setting div class font-size doesn't set the p element font size?

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

Here is my html file. I want to change the font size of all p element in the div. So I change the font size of the div containing all paragraphs but it doesn't work. Why?

```
 <div class="footersection__left--address">
         <p>2</p>
         <p>Melano Park,</p>
         <p>CA</p>
         <p>USA</p>
 </div>
```

Here is my SCSS file-

```
.footersection {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 6rem;

    &__left{
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        &--address{
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: aqua;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather you not nest CSS that way. If you'd like to access the p selector in the div class, you can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L4f0o6av/1/
Also, you can check this article about nesting: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: In the absence of any other CSS, the p would indeed inherit the font size and colour of the div, so apparently you have other css as well, which sets the p.

Comment: Or, it may be a caching problem; the browser could be looking at an older version of the stylesheet. Clear your cache and reload.

Comment: @MrLister you are right. I have just checked the resulting css code and yes, it should work like OP has defined. So I have deleted my answer because I was wrong. Thanks to pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS generated from this SCSS:

```
.footersection {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 6rem;

    &__left{
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        &--address{
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: aqua;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this CSS:

```
.footersection {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 6rem;
}
.footersection__left {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.footersection__left--address {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: aqua;
}
```

As you can see the `p` take the font size of the last selector `.footersection__left--address`.

Look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/abOzLjV).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Ale_info, your compiled CSS means that your `p` tags will inherit `font-size: 5rem` from `.footersection__left--address`. Or you have something else in your stylesheets setting the font-size on all `p` tags.

I also wanted to take the opportunity to tell you that you're using BEM wrong.

`--` defines a Modifier class, which should modify an existing Element class, thus should be appended to it. You're using a modifier on its own without the actual base styles for the element.

This is bad BEM:

```html
<div class="footersection">
  <div class="footersection__left--address"></div>
</div>
```

This is good BEM:

```html
<div class="footersection">
  <div class="footersection__left footersection__left--address"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with my BEM. I am still confused and don't know how to rightly use BEM. Can you suggest some good read on this topic?

Comment: @Y.R Lots of resources out there, have a look through this and see if it helps your understanding https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/